# Laurent expansion of different function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have two problems of expanding function to Laurent series:

1)find the Laurent expansion in the ${[z:R<|z|<\infty] }$ domain of the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}$, for $R$ bigger enough,what is the minimal R?

2)find the Laurent expansion of the function $f(z)=\frac{A}{z^2}+\frac{B}{z}+\frac{C}{z-1}$ in the domain $\Omega=\Bbb C/D_2(0) $, what are $A,B,C$ so $f$ would be holomorphic on $\Omega$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: ניסיתי לפתח את הטורים סביב הקטבים העניין במקרה הראשון שהם קטבים פשוטים, אז יש רק את השארית שהיא קבועה זאת לא איזשהי סדרה
  ולכן רדיוס ההתבדרות שניתן על ידי השארית בלבד תמיד תתן 1 ולכן המרחק 
מ0 יהיה לכל הפחות 2

 השאלה איך נראה הטור לורן הכולל פיתוח לטיילור ועוד שארית ,האם זה הטור טיילור הרגיל סביב z-i
ועוד השארית סביב הקוטב הפשוט?

בשאלה השנייה אני בכלל מסתבך,יש לי שני קטבים כל אחד מסדר שונה,אז יש לי 2 דרכים שונות לפתח את הפונקציה,

Comment: מה זה $D_2(0)$?  ותשתדל לכתוב ולקרוא באנגלית: במתמטיקה או במדעים בכלל זה הכי חשוב.

Comment: It's the open disc centerd in 0 with radius 2

Comment: The only limiting factor on the domains is that you cannot have poles or other singularities in the domain. The first function has poles at $\pm i$. So $R$ has to be big enough that they are not in the domain. The second has poles at $0$ and $1$, which already are not in $\Omega$, regardless of what values $A, B, C$ have.